# Where else magento save the customer details who has made an order except "sales_flat_order"?

Tags: magento-1.7, sales-order

I was searching the list of customer's name, email who has made orders.
Searching the internet I got to know that it is saved in the "**sales_flat_order**" table.

But in some record the **"firstname" and "lastname**" field have value **"NULL"**. But they have the "email address".

So is there **any other table** present where the customer (who has made the order) details are stored ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all tables prefixed with `sales_flat_order_`. This is how they are related:

```
                          +---------------------------------+
               +----------+ sales_flat_order_status_history |
               |        * +---------------------------------+
              1|
+--------------+---+ 1    +-----------------------+
| sales_flat_order +------+ sales_flat_order_item |
+--------+-----+---+    * +-----------------------+
       1 |   1 |
         |     |          +--------------------------+
         |     +----------+ sales_flat_order_address |
         |              * +--------------------------+
         |
         |
         |                +--------------------------+
         +----------------+ sales_flat_order_payment |
         |              1 +--------------------------+
         |
         |                +-----------------------+
         +----------------+ sales_flat_order_grid |
                        1 +-----------------------+
```

The email address is part of the customer data in `sales_flat_order`, but first name and last name are part of the shipping and billing addresses in `sales_flat_order_address`. Only if the order is associated to a registered customer, you will find the first name and last name *from the customer account* in `sales_flat_order`.

Answer (score 0):

**sales_flat_order_address** is the table where order addresses are stored. I reckon you will find data there.